# 'PATH_TO_FX' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Tags: javafx, command-line, command-prompt

I am currently following a set of instructions to install JavaFX for Windows. I have done the first few steps and stuck with this one.

[Step3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y8AaA.png)

I placed this in the prompt line `> set PATH_TO_FX="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"`

but it said that `'PATH_TO_FX' is not recognized as an internal or external command`

I am unsure what to do because the step is quite vague.

Comment: It just looks like you accidentally put a new line character between `set` and `PATH_TO_FX`.

Comment: Are you following the instructions at https://openjfx.io/openjfx-docs/?

Comment: It seems like either James_D's comment is right, or what seems to me that the ">" at the beginning of the command is not supposed to be part of the command.

Answer (score 2):

I *suspect* that you actually typed this at the command prompt:

```
> set PATH_TO_FX="C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"
```

To be clear, I *suspect* that you actually typed the `>` character.

It seems that that your Windows command interpreter is interpreting that as:

- redirect standard output to a file called `set`, and
- run a command called `PATH_TO_FX` with argument `"C:\Users\Admin\Downloads\openjfx-11.0.2_windows-x64_bin-sdk\javafx-sdk-11.0.2\lib"`

Of course there is no `PATH_TO_FX` command ... and hence the error message you are seeing.

Solution: don't type the `>`.

The `>`  in the instructions is actually supposed to be a shorthand for "run this at the **Windows** command prompt".  Likewise, `$`  is shorthand for "run this at the **Linux** (or whatever) shell prompt".   These are common documentation conventions when writing installation instructions.

Hint: that's what the respective *default* command / shell prompts look like.  (And, if you see `#` , that probably means "run this at a `root` shell prompt.)